# variable page size in linux

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management, linux-kernel

I was going through, paging concept in linux, where most of the time I found that page size is fix (default value is 4kb).

When I searched more over internet I found there is one POWER architecture from IBM which support variable size paging.

> https://www-304.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.performance/variable_large_page.htm

```
The POWER7® processor supports mixing 4 KB, 64 KB, and 16 MB page sizes within a single segment.
```

Here I did not get one thing whether this variable page size is handled during run time? I mean if variable page size can be allocated on demand at anytime?? and if yes then how is it possible?

If this not the right platform please move this question on right one.

Answer (score 2):

Linux has a fixed size of memory pages which is set to 4KB. Since this leads to a huge number of page entries to be managed by the MMU, Linux (RH) also supports transparent huge pages. This feature has to be enabled while booting and allows page sizes of 2Mb and 2GB. Be aware that the kernel is doing some kind of defragmentation which degrades performance. This can be switched off by writing 'never' to /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag.

Comment: my question is does this switching (4kb to 2Mb) happen during runtime or compile time??

Comment: This happens during run-time, but it's the decision of the kernel. The decision is made based on the amount of memory you want to allocate.